# If $a \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ has mean 0 and covariance $\Sigma$, what is $E[a^TC^TCa]$ where $C$ is a matrix of constants?

Tags: expected-value, matrix

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$ have mean vector 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Suppose $C$ is a $n \times p$ matrix of constants, how can I evaluate $E[a^TC^TCa]$?

I understand that I can pull $C$ outside of the expectation, but I'm not sure how to go about it when it's sandwiched between the $a$ vectors. How should I go about this?

Comment: It is hard to say. Suppose $a$ is from standard normal distribution and $C$ is identity matrix, then $a^Ta$ follows $\chi^2_p$ distribution, which has expected value of  $p$. However, if $a$ is not normal, then it is pretty complicated. Are you sure your question is not about $E(Caa^TC^T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=C^TC$, the expected value is a quadratic expression and can be written as
$$E[a^TMa]=\sum_{i,j} M_{ij}E[a_ia_j]=\sum_{i,j} M_{ij} \Sigma_{ij}$$
This is the sum of all elements in the element-wise multiplication of matrices $M$ and $\Sigma$. This is also equal to $\text{tr}(M^T\Sigma)=\text{tr}(M\Sigma)$.

Comment: to make it clearer, $E[a^TMa]=E[tr(a^TMa)]=E[tr(Maa^T)]=tr(ME[aa^T])=tr(M\Sigma)$

Comment: @Tan that's very practical

Comment: Perfect. Thank you both.

Comment: @gunes, In your answer you mentioned that it's equal to $tr(M^T\Sigma)$, should it be $tr(M\Sigma)$ instead?

Comment: For this particular question $M=M^T$